# sbackup-gtk not installable from 14.04

Tags: package-management, backup

I can't install sbackup on my laptop due to below reason:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install sbackup-gtk
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree   
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an
 impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required 
 packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following 
 information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sbackup-gtk :
 Depends: python-glade2 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: python-gnome2 but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sbackup-gtk` package is available at universe repository in Ubuntu 14.04. So run the below commands on terminal to install `sbackup-gtk`,

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbackup-gtk
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was because of my mirror server. I choose US server and everything works perfect now.